# Stuck on data manipulation

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```
name           charge          chargetype         filedate
Bob            CF              Violent            09/01/2016
Carl           CF              Non-Violent        08/07/2015
Lisa           CF              Non-Violent        07/03/2015
Louis          CF              Non-Violent        08/09/2018
```

I am trying to look at the total number and percent of cases that were both non-violent and happened before 07/01/2017. Here is my current code:

```
data %>%
     group_by(chargetype, filedate) %>%
     summarize(n_cases = n()) %>%
     filter(filedate < 07/01/2017) %>%
     summarize(n_nonviolent = sum(chargetype == "Non-Violent",
               n_violent = sum(chargetype == "Violent",
               n_total = n_nonviolent + n_violent,
               perc_nonviolent = (n_nonviolent/n_total)*100)
```

But it is giving me a blank result? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to convert the date to `Date` class i..e `data >%>% group_by(chargetype, filedate = dmy(filedate)) %>% summarise(n_cases = n()) %>% ungroup %>% filter(filedate <  dmy("07/01/2017"))`

Comment: So I think it's already in `mdy` Date format. But just for certainty sake, I tried out your code and unfortunately it returned an error message.

Answer (score 3):

As @akrun mentioned, you need to convert your Date variable to a Date object. You can use the baseR `as.Date()` function before summarizing like this:

`data$filedate <- as.Date(data$filedate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")`

Once this is done, continue with your `dplyr` construct but in the filter function, include the date within quotes, like this... `filter(filedate < "07/01/2017")`